# Hide Div After Click? (But what if the Div Is a banner?)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a webpage and i want to make a multi-ads space.
By clicking in the banner(it's link will be opened normally), i want that banner to be hidden and another one to be shown. But the problem's that banners is out of control!!

When i click on it, it will be shown in new window (normally), but no changes considering the div containing that banner that must be replaced by the next div containing the next banner.

I need to control displaying the DIVs by clicking under the banners.

You can see it in this webpage: http://allaroundtheworldtv.eu5.org/Test/new2a.html

In this example, a timer will start when clicking in the div out of the banner space. but what i want, that the timer start too when i click on the ad-banner. or even a solution to pass directly to the next banner.

Plz help me to do that!! i really want to do it as soon as possible!!

And think you.

Comment: Please show your code. We're not mind readers, we can't tell what you're doing wrong or how to fix it.

Comment: Show what you have currently done

Comment: i apologize because it isn't clear, and even i didn't find a way to add all the code. but i already modify it and i make a webpage that contain 3 ads and i want the timer to start when i click in the ad-banner not out of it. Link: http://allaroundtheworldtv.eu5.org/Test/new2a.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your banner is in an iframe (generally they work like this) you can't make such as actions. Because it is in another domain and DOM object.

If you are serving your banners from your html, this is possible with a basic "onclick" event of div.

Comment: actually they are iframe and script. i already make a webpage that contain 3 ads and i'm looking a way that can allow me to start the timer when i click inside the ad. Link: http://allaroundtheworldtv.eu5.org/Test/new2a.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [jQuery](https://jquery.com/), you can do this pretty easily. Assuming the region you want to click has an id of "clickable" and the region you want to hide has an id of "toHide", run the following javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#clickable').click(function() {
    $('#toHide').hide();
  });
});
```

Comment: i try that but it didn't work for me. i want when i click on the banner i hide it. i already add a webpage that contain 3 banners with a timer; it will start when you click on the div but didn't when you click in the banner. look on this page:http://allaroundtheworldtv.eu5.org/Test/new2a.html